# Is there any way to declare a const reference to a method at compile-time?

Tags: delphi

I'm working on a script interpreter, that I've managed to get to a working state.  It has a compiler that parses the script and generates bytecode, and a VM that executes the bytecode.

At the heart of the interpreter is a loop with a giant `case` statement that looks something like this:

```
case CurrentOpcode.Operation of
  OP_1: DoOp1(CurrentOpcode);
  OP_2: DoOp2(CurrentOpcode);
  ...
  OP_N: DoOpN(CurrentOpcode);
end;
```

Profiling tells me that, for whatever reason, my script execution is spending a significant amount of time inside that `case` statement, which seems strange to me, so I'm looking for a way to optimize it.  The obvious solution, since all the operation functions basically have the same signature, is to create an array of method pointers indexed by the opcode's `Operation` value.  But `Operation` is declared as an enum, and it would be nice to be able to declare this as a const array so that if I add more opcodes in the future, the compiler can remind me to update the array.

Since a method pointer stores runtime state, (the `Self` reference to the object it's running against,) I can't create a const array of method pointers.  (Nor would this be a good idea anyway, as it's quite likely that I'll end up with more than one script running at the same time.)  But methods are just syntactic sugar anyway.  Something like:

```
procedure TMyObject.DoSomething(x, y: integer);
```

really means:

```
procedure TMyObject_DoSomething(Self: TMyObject; x, y: integer);
```

So I should be able to declare a function pointer type in the latter form and assign it that way, and then I'd just have to explicitly pass `Self` as the first parameter when I invoke it.  But the compiler doesn't like that.

```
type TOpcodeProc = procedure (Self: TScriptVM; Opcode: TOpcode);
const OPCODE: TOpcodeProc = TScriptVM.DoOp1;

[DCC Error]: E2009 Incompatible types: 'regular procedure and method pointer'
```

I've tried different variations on this to try to get it to compile, but they all give errors.  Is there any way to get this to compile?

Comment: Another way to handle this is to replace the enum with a list of descendants of whatever class CurrentOperation is. Instead of setting Operation, create an instance of the opcode-specific descendant class. Make `DoOp` a virtual (abstract) method of the class, and then replace your entire case statement with a single statement: `CurrentOperation.DoOp`. You can have an array of class references indexed by the opcode enum to decide which class to instantiate.

Comment: @Rob: Yes, that would probably work, but considering that the stated goal here is to improve performance, switching the current situation out for something like that, which would add significant overhead for object creation and virtual dispatch, really doesn't sound like a good idea...

Comment: How much overhead would it really be? You'd look up the class reference with an array. You'd create an object, which you're already doing anyway. Virtual dispatch is just a pointer lookup, which you'd get anyway from your proposed idea of storing partial method pointers in an array.

Comment: @Rob: There's no object creation going on in the current system. The opcodes are very simple records, to make serialization easier. (The script "program" is an array of opcode records, and so the entire thing can be block-written to a stream and read back the same way.)

Comment: @Mason: Have you looked how it is compiled? IMHO typical assembly code (and Delphi produce one) for such case statement is jump table and 'indexed' jump like this: cmp `cmp edx,lowerbound,  jnbe  exit,  jmp dword ptr [edx*4 + tableoffset]  `. IMHO if this statement waste a time, it is due passing CurrentOpCode (what is its type - record? if yes, it is passed by value and copied each time).

Comment: @MasonWheeler NGLN got it right, you can have a "InstrucCallTable" for each of your instructions and a "OpCallTable" for your operations, so you can have InstrucCallTable[_INSTRUCTION](...) followed by OpCallTable[_OPCODE](...); this will make your code very easy to follow.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Declaration:

```
const
  OPCODE: array[TOperation] of Pointer = (
    @TScriptVM.DoOp1, 
    @TScriptVM.DoOp2, 
    ... 
    @TScriptVM.DoOpN
  );
```

Call:

```
TOpcodeProc(OPCODE[CurrentOpcode.Operation])(Self, CurrentOpcode);
```

More cool stuff:

```
var
  OpCodeProcs: array[TOperation] of TOpCodeProc absolute OPCODE;
```

Much nicer syntax to call the method:

```
OpCodeProcs[CurrentOpcode.Operation](Self, CurrentOpcode);
```

Good thing is because of the absolute to the constant the compiler prevents you from assigning something to the OpCodeProcs variable!

Comment: You can hide the call inside a method and inline the method. like : `procedure TScriptVM.DoOp( CurrentOpCode : TCurrentOperation); inline;` and implementation: 
`procedure TScriptVM.DoOp( CurrentOpCode : TCurrentOperation);
begin
  OpCodeProcs[CurrentOpCode.Operation](Self, CurrentOpcode);
end;`. Looks a little bit better and almost equally fast.

Answer (score 5):

No solution for the constant part of your question, but here's how your could eliminate the `case`:

```
type
  TTestMethod = procedure(Instance: TObject; Param1, Param2: Integer);

  TTest = class(TObject)
  private
    FMethods: array[0..1] of TTestMethod;
    procedure InitMethods;
    procedure CallMethod(ID: Integer; Param1, Param2: Integer);
  protected
    procedure TestMethod0(Param1, Param2: Integer);
    procedure TestMethod1(Param1, Param2: Integer);
  end;

procedure TTest.InitMethods;
begin
  FMethods[0] := TTestMethod(@TTest.TestMethod0);
  FMethods[1] := TTestMethod(@TTest.TestMethod1);
end;

procedure TTest.CallMethod(ID: Integer; Param1, Param2: Integer);
begin
  FMethods[ID](Self, Param1, Param2);
end;
```

Comment: Mason makes it perfectly clear that he already knows how to populate an array at runtime.